# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS null pointer crash

Tags: apt, kernel

Ok, I think I'm in a Bad Place(TM). I'd gotten too trusting--the Ubuntu kernel updates have been solid for a very long time. I downloaded the latest 3.2.0-51-generic-pae kernel, ran it for a week or so, then cleaned the previous kernel image out (since my /boot was undersized). This server has been running reliably for--well, a very long time.

Now I tried the latest apt-get update and upgrade, and the package libapt-inst1.4 failed. Two files in `/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES` -- libapt-inst1.4.mo and libapt-pkg4.12.mo -- were "strange" Permissions are all qustion marks, as are the owner/group, size, and date fields.  I tried to move that directory off to `LC_MESSAGES_BAD` and recreating it with the same permissions, but without those two files. It works. BUT.

I can't reinstall `libapt-inst1.4`. It fails with a kernel `NULL` pointer.  Now, I don't think that's actually a problem with the package -- I think the kernel has a problem.  But, of course, I removed the previous kernel.

Does anyone else have an issue with the 3.2.0-15 kernel?  Or the libapt-inst1.4 package? I'm feeling a bit vulnerable here -- it's all *working*, but I can't apply any updates.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some file system corruption. Maybe problems will be fixed by fixing the corruption.

To force fsck all file systems on next boot
    sudo touch /forcefsck

You need to have console access to answer possible fsck questions.
Need to 
     sudo rm /forcefsck
when no longer needed.